# Bounded non constant multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Show that there does not exist a non-constant continuous function $f:R^{2}  \to R$ such that $f(x,y)=5$ for all $(x,y)$ with $x^{2}+y^{2}<1$

My approach: I was able to reason out and prove this intuitively but not mathematically. I first drew a circle on the $XY$ axis of radius 1 centered at origin.  This bounded all the possible values of $x$ and $Y$ inside the circle. Now imagining that as a gradient plane where $z=5$ I took values from inside the circle. If the function is to give an output of 5 for all the values of $X\ and \ Y$ then somehow the X and Y need to be eliminated. I cannot use higher powers of X and Y as then the function would converge and never be equal to 5. If I was to take a function of the type $aX + bY = 5$ then it wouldn't be possible to select such real values of a and b to account for all the possible X and Y values. Therefore the function can only be a constant but since that isn't allowed, I can safely say that a non constant continuous function in the given domain $X,\ Y \ in\ [0,1) $ does not exist.

My question: How do I approach this mathematically so as to prove this ? I tried putting what I wrote above more "mathematically" but it didn't seem like a substantial proof or even resemble one.

Comment: It should be $f: \Bbb R^2 \mapsto \Bbb R$, no?

Comment: You should work on a bit more MathJax. :) For a mapping, use $\to$ — written \to. (@RhysHughes is actually wrong. $\mapsto$ is used to indicate where an *element* goes, not the mapping as a whole.)

Comment: I've made the required changes

Comment: Great, @ShauryaGoyal. Let me know if you have questions on my answer.

Comment: @TedShifrin i have replied to your answer please see that. from what i understand, for values less than 1, the function you've defined is constant which is exactly what is not allowed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course there are lots of such continuous functions. You can even make them as smooth as you want. Here's one example. Define $f\colon\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ by
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 5, & x^2+y^2\le 1 \\ 6-(x^2+y^2), & x^2+y^2>1\end{cases}.$$
You could make something that looks conical by taking
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 5, & x^2+y^2\le 1 \\ 6-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, & x^2+y^2>1\end{cases}.$$
It might help to think about functions $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and draw some pictures, and then move on to two variables.

Comment: Both of these functions are constant on the range given, which it is *obviously* the intention of the "non-constant" condition to avoid.

Comment: No, @RhysHughes. Before saying "obviously" condescendingly, you should reread the question. $f(x,y) = 5$ *for all* $(x,y)$ with $x^2+y^2<1$. That said, I read only the question and not the OP's paragraph of discussion.

Comment: @TedShifrin the functions you've just described are constant as long as $x^{2}+y^{2}<1$. The question is not considered with values beyond 1. I would need to prove that a function which as the terms x and y in it does not exist. What happens beyond 1 is of no concern to the question. BTW I don't mean to sound rude here . ireally need help

Comment: @TedShifrin I apologise for being condescending, but I read the question, and understand it is not perfectly written. The solution you present, while correct to the exact question as written, is too obvious to have been overlooked by whomever asked the question - note they are asking for a proof that **no** such functions exist. Instead, the question would be better posed as "Show that there does not exist a non-constant, continuous function $f: B(0,1)\subset \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ s.t. $f(x,y)=5 \ \forall (x,y)\in B(0,1)$

Comment: @RhysHughes I have entered the question as it is

Comment: The question is incorrect as written, @ShauryaGoyal. You obviously have a constant function on the ball of radius $1$ centered at the origin. They specifically asked for a function with domain all of $\Bbb R^2$.  So something is wrong. There are lots of continuous functions — indeed infinitely differentiable functions — that are constant on large open sets. If the function is *real analytic* rather than just continuous, then the only answer is the constant function. You should contact your professor for clarification.

Comment: P.S. @ShauryaGoyal I was a professor for close to 40 years. I can tell you from experience that professors make typographical mistakes and sloppy errors. When they're on exams, it's particularly maddening to the students. Ask your professor to double-check or explain.

Comment: @TedShifrin okay so if i modify the question to remove all the real numbers and just restrict the domain to the ball would that be correct ? my professor has said that this is for practice and will not be discussed. When i asked him for hints or what additional theorem is used, he just read the question 10 times and said "okay so you do that" without any hint. he has not taught whatever theorem required to solve this.

Comment: What course are you taking? If I give you a function that's defined on a domain $D$ and ask you to prove that it's the only function with those values on $D$, it's a silly question. A function is uniquely determined by its values at every point of its domain, and if you've specified all of those, there's nothing more to say.

Comment: @TedShifrin okay i shall ask him again. Thank you so much !

Comment: @TedShifrin my course is titled advanced calculus which is basically just multivariable. it has a few proofs like epsilon-delta, continuity, differentiability but besides that convergence etc isn't even mentioned in the class or the professor's slides. Your last part makes sense. Ill include that reasoning in my email to the professor.

Comment: Let me know what the professor finally says. This seems crazy to me. By the way, if you're doing advanced calculus, you might find my YouTube videos helpful from time to time. Check them out if you're so inclined.